# Woocommerce: $_GET custom parameter (link in new order mail) to updale Woocommerce order status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When a user makes an order the order is set to on hold and the new order email is sent to the shop with a link to confirm the order. I can add the link but I can't make it to change the status of the order (to processing) in Woocommerce when I click on the link the email.

This is how I add the link to the email (this part works)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'ct_add_link_to_new_order__email', 20, 4 );

function ct_add_link_to_new_order__email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
   if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {

      $link = '<p>';

      $link .= '<a href="'. get_site_url() .'/order/s='. absint( $order->id ) .'" >';

      $link .= pll__( 'Click here to go confirm the order' );

      $link .= '</a>';

      $link .= '</p>';

     echo $link;


   }
}
```

This is how I thought I would get the parameter and change the order status

```
add_action( 'init', 'ct_confirm_order');
function ct_confirm_order(){
      if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ){
         $order_id = intval( $_GET['s'] );
         $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
         $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
         $order->update_status( "processing" );
         return;
         }   
}
```

When I click the link I get a 404 page does not exist (I created an Order page) and the status is not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't just use the $_GET superglobal to grab our query variable

Instead you have to access the query_vars property of the $wp_query object.

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['s'])) {
 $sMsdsCat = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['s']);
}
```

you also need to tell WordPress how to populate that query variable

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
 $aNewRules = array('order/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=order&s=$matches[1]');
 $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
 return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Hi Sabry, thank you for your time. You're right, I did see something about `$wp_query->query_vars` and I tried but most likely I did it wrong. So with your code I managed to have the new order status set but I need to change the URL structure from mydomain/order/s to mydomain/oder?s=order_id otherwise nothing happens...and I still get a 404 no matter what! If you have more ideas...thanks!

Comment: Hi again, seems that I can't edit my previous comment so as an update...

I managed to have the new order status set but I had to change the URL structure from `mydomain/order/s=order_id` 
to `mydomain/oder/?st=order_id`. 

Also, as note to self, **s** is a WP reserved term (as I found out while looking again at how to pass a parameter to avoid a 404). So thanks again for your time.